# LocalDateTime (or any other suitable class) with time as optional paramter

Tags: java, java-time, localdate, datetimeformatter

I am trying to parse an incoming string which might contain time or not. Both the following dates should be accepted

```
"2022-03-03" and "2022-03-03 15:10:05".
```

The DateTimeFormatter that I know will fail in any one of the cases. This is one answer I got, but I don't know if in any ways time part can be made optional here.

[ISO_DATE_TIME.format() to LocalDateTime with optional offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57559087/iso-date-time-format-to-localdatetime-with-optional-offset)

The idea is if the time part is not present I should set it to the end of the day, so the time part should be 23:59:59.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try parsing it to `LocalDateTime`, if that fails, try parsing it to `LocalDate` and the append the "time" component to that to get a `LocalDateTime`.  You "could" use a regular expression, but you only be testing for the existence of numbers where the time should be, not verifying that the values are actually correct

Comment: I can try to do that. But this might raise the question, what if parsing LocalDate fails, because the "data" might be corrupted like if only year part comes "2025".

Comment: Then you need to handle those possibilities - if neither the `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` parse the input, then assume the input is incorrect - again, if it's "really" important, you could use a regular expression, but again, even if it passes, that's not guarantee that the data represents a valid date/time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could utilize a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to specify defaults for missing fields:

```java
private static LocalDateTime parse(String str) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("uuuu-MM-dd[ HH:mm:ss]")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 59)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 59)
        .toFormatter();
    return LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
}
```

The pattern specifies the pattern it will try to parse. Note that the square brackets (`[]`) are *optional parts*. Everything between them will be either completely consumed, or entirely discarded.

With `parseDefaulting` you can specify the default values for when fields are missing. In your case, if the user provides only the date, the hour-of-day, minute-of-hour and second-of-minute fields are missing, that's why it is needed to provide defaults for them.

---

Example

```java
System.out.println(parse("2022-03-03"));
System.out.println(parse("2022-03-03 15:10:05"));
System.out.println(parse("2025"));
```

Outputs the following:

```
2022-03-03T23:59:59
2022-03-03T15:10:05
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2025' could not be parsed at index 4
```

Comment: Learned something today, thanks.